# jQuery Multi Layer JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

Good Evening,
I am working on a JSON that I have to parse to get what I need.  It looks like this:

```
{
    "0":{"ID":"282","WarrSalePrice":"1.00"}
    ,"1":{"ID":"283","WarrSalePrice":"2.00"}
    ,"2":{"ID":"284","WarrSalePrice":"3.00"}
    ,"3":{"ID":"285","WarrSalePrice":"4.00"}
    ,"Totals":{"RowCount":"4","WarrSalePrice":"10.00"}
}
```

I am using the following code to traverse the JSON above.

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
    alert(value['WarrSalePrice']);    //This get the individual sales prices
});
```

The problem is I need to get the RowCount and TotalSalesPrice.  And my logic here is not getting it done. It tells me that my value if "undefined" for the 5th (Totals Row).  I also need to read the RowCount value before the jQuery.each is ever called.  Because if the RowCount == 0, there is no need to do the jQuery.each.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, please.

All the best,
George

Comment: why wouldn't you just access it via `data.Totals.RowCount`?

Comment: Oh, the answer to that is very simple.  I know much less than you about this.  Thanks for the answer. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mvpb1k1r/

Just check if its undefined or not.

```
var data = {
    "0":{"ID":"282","WarrSalePrice":"1.00"}
    ,"1":{"ID":"283","WarrSalePrice":"2.00"}
    ,"2":{"ID":"284","WarrSalePrice":"3.00"}
    ,"3":{"ID":"285","WarrSalePrice":"4.00"}
    ,"Totals":{"RowCount":"4","WarrSalePrice":"10.00"}
}

jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
    if(typeof value['WarrSalePrice'] != "undefined") {
    console.log("WarrSalePrice: " + value['WarrSalePrice']);    //This get the individual sales prices
    }

  if(typeof value['RowCount'] != "undefined") {
    console.log("RowCount: " + value['RowCount']);    //This get the individual sales prices
    }
});
```